# Dependency injection in non-global activity scope done right. How to provide special MyActivity as Activity

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I am using dependency injection to provide global objects (`@Singleton`) and non global objects for activities only (`@ActivityScoped`).

Now I wonder if I did it right and if it could be done better. The most interesting part of this DI implementation is the injection of the object `SomeManager` into 2 different activities with restricted scope

Here is the code

The main app component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    ApplicationModule::class,
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityModule::class,
    ManagerModule::class,
    ...
    ClientModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): AppComponent.Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

The appclication module

```
@Module
abstract class ApplicationModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    internal abstract fun bindContext(application: Application): Context

}
```

The module for the activities

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [MainActivityModule::class])
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [LoginActivityModule::class])
    internal abstract fun loginActivity(): LoginActivity
}
```

And now I want to inject a new `SomeManager` to the `LoginActivity` and a new one to the `MainActivity`.

The approach is having a module for each activity like you see above in the `@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules...` annotation. The implementations of the 2 files look like this

```
@Module
object MainActivityModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    internal fun provideSomeManager(activity: MainActivity, apiClient: ApiClient) =
            SomeManager(activity, apiClient)
}
```

And

```
@Module
object LoginActivityModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    internal fun provideSomeManager(activity: LoginActivity, apiClient: ApiClient) =
            SomeManager(activity, apiClient)
}
```

The Question:

**1)** Now the `LoginActivityModule` and `MainActivityModule` look very similar. Is there a better approach to provide `SomeManager` to both activities without making them `@Singleton` and withouth creating a module for each activity (becaues `SomeManager` only needs an `Activity`, not a special sublcass)? I had something in mind like that it only takes an `Activity` instead of a specific `XXXActivity`. **But how can I tell dagger to provide the `XXXActivity` as `Activity`**

**2)** And beside that optimizing in 1), is this a correct implementation?

#### Update 1

I have solved it by the following implementation. **Is this the right way to do this?**

Module that provides the `MainActivity` as `Activity`

```
@Module
object MainActivityModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    internal fun provideAsActivity(activity: MainActivity): Activity = activity
}
```

Module that provides the `MainActivity` as `Activity`

```
@Module
object LoginActivityModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    internal fun provideAsActivity(activity: LoginActivity): Activity = activity
}
```

A Manager module that is only `@ActivityScoped`

```
@Module
object ManagerModule2 {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    internal fun provideSomeManager(activity: Activity, apiClient: ApiClient) =
            SomeManager(activity, apiClient)
}
```

And the Android injector for the activities

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ManagerModule2::class, MainActivityModule::class])
    internal abstract fun mainActivity(): MainActivity

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [ManagerModule2::class, LoginActivityModule::class])
    internal abstract fun loginActivity(): LoginActivity
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now the `LoginActivityModule` and `MainActivityModule` look very similar. Is there a better approach to provide `SomeManager` to both activities without making them `@Singleton`? I had something in mind like that it only takes an `Activity` instead of a specific `XXXActivity`.

Yes, you could do that. You can replace the dependency on the specific Activity and replace it with `Activity` or `Context` (depending on your actual needs) and move that declaration into a separate module, which you could include in both of your ActivityModules.

```
@Module
object SomeManagerModule {

    @JvmStatic
    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    internal fun provideSomeManager(activity: Activity, apiClient: ApiClient) =
            SomeManager(activity, apiClient)
}
```

And either include it with the module or add it to `ContributesAndroidInjector`.

```
@Module(includes = [SomeManagerModule::class])
object MainActivityModule { /* ... */ }

// or

@ActivityScoped
@ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [LoginActivityModule::class, SomeManagerModule::class])
internal abstract fun loginActivity(): LoginActivity
```

And you could even remove the need for a module completely by using Constructor Injection.

```
@ActivityScoped
SomeManager @Inject constructor(activity: Activity, apiClient: ApiClient)
```

Either way you would have to bind / provide your `xxxActivity`s as a `Activity` somewhere so that Dagger can find them.

> And beside that optimizing in 1), is this a correct implementation?

Looks good to me. You said you wanted a new manager per Activity, so `@ActivityScoped` seems the correct choice. You could possibly remove the scope completely if you don't have to ensure that there is only ever one per Activity-scoped component, but this depends on your exact usecase.

Comment: Thanks, but `Either way you would have to bind / provide your xxxActivitys as a Activity somewhere so that Dagger can find them.` is the reason why I came this way. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have found a way, but unsure if thats the way to do it. See update #1

Comment: @martynmlostekk Yes, looks about right. And as mentioned, you could use Constructor injection and remove the need for the manager module completely